# ODE system with "parameter" which is a (piecewise) function of one of the dependent variables

Tags: differential-equations

I have a 2-dimensional dynamical system where time (t) is the independent variable. My ultimate aim is to perform stability analysis, but I bumped into a problem related to the construction of the model and its translation to code.

Basically, one of the "parameters" of the model (let's call it p) is a piecewise function of one of the two dependent variables (which is a function of time, of course).

Here is the definition of the dynamical system:

```
system = {

y'[t] == p[z[t]] y[t] + (1-p[z[t]]) (1 - y[t]),
z'[t] == a - r z[t], 

p[z_[t_]] == Piecewise[{
             {0, z[t] < C_LOW},
             {(z[t] - C_LOW)/(C_HIGH - C_LOW), C_LOW <= z[t] < C_HIGH}, 
             {1, z[t] >= C_HIGH]}}]

}
```

How can I write such a function of a variable in a Mathematica ODE system?

Comment: Apparently you mixed up uppercase and lowercase `p`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, this is doable through a judicious combination of `Clip[]` and `Rescale[]`:

```
p[x_, {cLow_, cHigh_}] := Rescale[Clip[x, {cLow, cHigh}], {cLow, cHigh}]

With[{a = 2, r = -1, cLow = 1, cHigh = 3, y0 = 1, z0 = 0}, 
     DSolve[{y'[t] == p[z[t], {cLow, cHigh}] y[t] +
                      (1 - p[z[t], {cLow, cHigh}]) (1 - y[t]),
             z'[t] == a - r z[t], y[0] == y0, z[0] == z0}, {y, z}, t]]
```

(I had removed `x` since it was not part of the coupled equations, and can be solved on its own.)

```
Plot[Evaluate[{y[x], z[x]} /. %], {x, -2, 2}]
```

[image: a plot]

Comment: Nice result (and gets my upvote). But is there any reason not to do this sort of problem using `Piecewise` as is, and `NDSolve`? For that matter, will `DSolve` handle it? (I have not tried, but I'd have thought it would prefer that function to `Rescale/Clip`.)

Comment: `DSolve[]` returns a result full of exponentials within `Piecewise[]` constructs, yes. (Well, at least in this particular case. In the general case, I get an `Integrate::pwrl` error and a relatively complicated expression for `y`, since I haven't told `DSolve[]` that the parameters are real.) I don't see why a direct `Piecewise[]` wouldn't work, but it was amusing to me that the "limiting" function `p` is expressible in terms of `Clip[]` + `Rescale[]`.

Comment: As for `NDSolve[]`: I think it would be better to use an appropriate `WhenEvent[]` than use a `Piecewise[]` in that case.

Comment: notice the `z` equation decouples too, so you can readily get the transition points in simple form ( the first is `Log[(a - r z0)/(a - cLow r)]/r` )

Comment: @george, I noticed, but that would have made for a longer answer than I wanted to write. In any case, that is definitely a useful result you have.

Comment: Good point about using `WhenEvent`.

Comment: First of all, thanks to all for answers and comments. I'm learning a lot from both. And sorry if I presented an easier version of the dynamical system where not all equations were coupled.

Comment: Shouldn't y[t] be continuous? I would like its derivative to be discontinuous, and not having an abrupt change in the values of y[t]. I think it's not a model-specific issue, as I tried with an easier equation (y'[t] == (1 - p[z[t], {cLow, cHigh}] )  y[t] ) and I get the same trouble